# Why does the CSS layout look so poor on small devices?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a web site where users can search for customers. Part of the search allows them to filter by country, state or city. In order to balance flexibility for those on big devices and a neat UI for those on small devices, I've added four input controls, one each for country, state and region, all to be shown on big devices, and one combined control for location to be shown in small devices.

This is all using the standard stuff that comes when you start a new MVC project in Visual Studio 2013. The HTML looks like this...

```
<div class="form-inline form-group" id="filterGroup">
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><label for="namefilter">Name:</label>&nbsp;<input id="namefilter" type="text" class="form-control k-input k-textbox" /></span>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><label for="locationfilter" class="visible-xs">Location:</label>&nbsp;<input id="locationfilter" type="text" class="form-control k-input k-textbox visible-xs" /></span>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><label for="countryfilter" class="hidden-xs">Country:</label>&nbsp;<input id="countryfilter" type="text" class="form-control k-input k-textbox hidden-xs" /></span>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><label for="regionfilter" class="hidden-xs">State:</label>&nbsp;<input id="regionfilter" type="text" class="form-control k-input k-textbox hidden-xs" /></span>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><label for="cityfilter" class="hidden-xs">City:</label>&nbsp;<input id="cityfilter" type="text" class="form-control k-input k-textbox hidden-xs" /></span>
<span style="white-space: nowrap"><button id="filterBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Filter</button>&nbsp;<button id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Clear</button></span>
</div>
```

Now when you view this on a big device, it looks fine...
[image: filter controls on a big device]

(Note that the HTML appears inside the toolbar section of a KendoUI grid, but that's not relevant to the problem, as the issue is exactly the same if I place it directly in the body of the document)

However, if you view it on a small device (or just make the browser window narrow), it looks poor...
[image: filter controls on a small device]

The location textbox is on a separate line from the label, which it shouldn't be, as they are both wrapped in a span with white-space set to nowrap, there is a large margin above the location textbox, and the two buttons are pushed down onto yet another line. All of this should fit on one line, but instead looks ugly and takes up far too much space.

Any ideas what I did wrong? I want the name and location controls on one line, preferably with the buttons as well.

Comment: What about putting `.form-inline` in a bootstrap `<div class="row">`

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but I tried this a few ways, and it didn't make any difference. Please can you explain a bit more. Thx

Comment: The `<div class="row">` keeps the elements inline. You should then however add bootstrap `.col-` classes on the children to keep a [12 grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Problem is that the controls are going to go inside the KendoUI grid's toolbar section, and that won't be using the Bootstrap grid system. I'm actually not using the grid system at all on this page, I'm just allowing the grid to take as much width as it has. Any other ideas? Thx

Comment: You could add `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` to each span. Otherwise you might want to check out using @media queries in your css

Comment: Ah, media queries did it! It seems that Bootstrap was adding a "display:block !important" style to the textbox when it was shown, and my attempts to override this inline were ignored (not sure why). I added a media query and set the display to inline !important, and it works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want proper responsive layout using BootStrap3, you should use the 12-grid system.

In your form, use the `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col-md-2">` (or whatever size suits you) in order to properly format it.

More specific to forms, you have an example of a properly formatted one here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

More info here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm actually putting these controls inside the KendoUI grid's toolbar, so they wouldn't be part of the grid system anyway. Is there a way to do what I want without the Bootstrap grid? Thx

Comment: Are you still using the Bootstrap styling (just not grid) or do you want some custom CSS completely independent of Bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using the Bootstrap stuff, as that gives me the visibility. I don't mind custom CSS, as long as it works!

Comment: Your best bet, as @gerdi suggested, would be to look into `@media` queries and use them in your styling to define specific style for each kind of screen size. You can find some good info here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Yup, turned out that way. Pls see my comment there. Thanks for the help